# Cassandra Internal Error

Tags: cassandra, internal, reddit

I'm trying to install reddit manually on my computer; using [this](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/Install-guide) guide. I'm running into an error trying to get Cassandra set up.

The install guide says to:

```
    $ cassandra-cli -h localhost
    [default@unknown] create keyspace reddit with strategy_options = [{replication_factor:1}];
    [default@unknown] use reddit;
    [default@unknown] create column family permacache with column_type = 'Standard' and comparator = 'BytesType';
```

When I `create keyspace reddit with strategy_options = [{replication_factor:1}];`, it returns `org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing system_add_keyspace`.

What should I do to fix this? I'm running Linux Mint 13 MATE 32bit.

Comment: Have a look in the cassandra log, normally in /var/log/cassandra/system.log.  Whenever there is an Internal error it usually means there is an exception in the log that you should check.  If there is, please paste it and it might show what the cause is.